# Configuring domain on Heroku doesn't work

Tags: heroku, dns

I have an app on Heroku (works great) and I want to add a custom domain to it. I added it in the CLI:

```
heroku domains:add mydomain.com
```

and configured the CNAME on `domain.com` to the dns target. (not my herokuapp domain).

This was 24 hours ago. From what I read this should work, but the domain is not propagating according to `www.whatsmydns.net`.

I spoke with the support people at `domain.com` and they say it's propagating on their side.

What am I missing?

EDIT: screenshot of my domain provider CNAME record:

[image]

Comment: Can you share the real domain name

Comment: @DusanBajic it's deepdao.world

Comment: I don't see any CNAME set, can you screenshot your DNS web UI?

Comment: @DusanBajic I added it to the question.

Comment: Well, `heroku.deepdao.world` is correctly `CNAME`d to `afternoon-beet-xi91pucszpz0epndkflwhrui.herokudns.com.`, but not your apex(root) domain. Take a look at https://help.heroku.com/NH44MODG/my-root-domain-isn-t-working-what-s-wrong

Comment: @DusanBajic I added PointDNS and I'm trying to add my domain to it, but it says the domain is managed by another account and doesn't add it. What's the full process at this point?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you did all the steps right:

1-

```
heroku domains:add example.com --app <app name>

heroku domains:add www.example.com --app <app name>

heroku domains:add *.example.com --app <app name>
```

This is to point your domain name from heroku side

2- 
From the domain name website in the

```
TYPE-> CNAME
HOST -> WWW
POINTS TO -> your heroku url
```

Check out this video its about connecting your domain name to godaddy. I think its the same way with domain.co youtube.com/watch?v=kKGSGT7mSnQ&t=75s

Please let me know if this does work for you :)

Comment: Thanks @nourza. I added the domain, the `www` and the `*.`. But the heroku instruction seem to be to add the `dns target` and not the herokuapp url.

Comment: Also, on domain.com you don't have a `host`. Just `Type`, and `Content` which is the url to point to. Their support says the CNAME is set up correctly.

Comment: Maybe change the name to www

Comment: Check this page https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Comment: I edited my answer. Try to add app name in the end of the command